# Google Play Games C++ SDK Samples fails with Library 'ButtonClickerNativeActivity' not found

Tags: android, c++, google-play-games

I need to experiment with the [Google Play Games C++ SDK Samples for Android](https://github.com/playgameservices/cpp-android-basic-samples).

Running it from an emulator fails to sign in requesting to install the [Google Play Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games)... which requires to be done manually, as I understand...

Running it from the Samsung Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 GT-N8010 executing Android 4.1.2, the Button Clicker application fails at launch with the following error:

> Cannot load library: load_library[1094]: Library
>   'ButtonClickerNativeActivity' not found

*Note: This error does not show up when I run it from the emulator.*

I don't understand why this fails and how to fix or work around this failure.

The sample loads the so this way:

```
public class ButtonClickerNativeActivity extends NativeActivity {
    // Load SO
    static {
        System.load("libButtonClickerNativeActivity.so");
    }
```

I confirm the package (ButtonClicker-debug.apk) contains the library in lib folder for armeabi, armeabi-v7a and x86.

Here is the logcat listing of the app start up:

```
01-28 15:18:44.885 31258-31258/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-28 15:18:44.900 31258-31264/? E/jdwp: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
01-28 15:18:44.900 31258-31264/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-28 15:18:44.945 31258-31258/? W/ActivityThread: Application com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-28 15:18:44.960 31258-31258/? I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
01-28 15:18:45.915 31258-31264/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
01-28 15:18:45.965 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker I/System.out: Debugger has connected
01-28 15:18:45.965 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 15:18:46.165 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 15:18:46.365 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 15:18:46.565 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 15:18:46.765 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 15:18:46.965 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 15:18:47.170 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-28 15:18:47.370 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker I/System.out: debugger has settled (1325)
01-28 15:18:47.510 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib ButtonClickerNativeActivity 0x423b2428
01-28 15:18:47.515 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker W/dalvikvm: Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/google/example/games/ButtonClicker/ButtonClickerNativeActivity;
01-28 15:18:47.515 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker W/dalvikvm: Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/google/example/games/ButtonClicker/ButtonClickerNativeActivity;)
01-28 15:18:47.515 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-28 15:18:47.515 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c3d2a0)
01-28 15:18:47.525 31258-31258/com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                                            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library[1094]: Library 'ButtonClickerNativeActivity' not found
                                                                                            at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:340)
                                                                                            at java.lang.System.load(System.java:521)
                                                                                            at com.google.example.games.ButtonClicker.ButtonClickerNativeActivity.(ButtonClickerNativeActivity.java:29)
                                                                                            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) 
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-28 15:18:58.720 31258-31258/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31258 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you share a log of the app starting up?

Comment: Were you able to do the steps to build the project before building and deploying it to the device? There's a prerequisite that you need [Google Play Game Service C++ SDK](https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/) and unzip it to a `.gpg-cpp-sdk` directory. There are also other prerequisites based on the .md file of the `samples-android/` and `ButtonClicker/" folders.

Comment: Yes, I built it succesfully since it executes on the emulator (the application runs, but the sign in fails because Google Play application is not installed).

Also, the instruction to unzip to a .pgp-cpp-sdk folder is unclear?... Where am I supposed to put this folder? (In fact, I figured out it was required in the common\gpg-sdk folder and precisely with the "gpg-cpp-sdk" name with NOT prefix with a "."...)

Comment: I did not provision the ids.xml file with an identifier (yet)... could that lead to such different behavior between the emulator and a real device?

<string name="app_id">REPLACE_ME</string>

Comment: From what I know Google Play Services isn't installed in the emulator's system images. Its better to test it out on an actual device. Hopefully it won't be an issue on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the following line in the sample code (ButtonClickerNativeActivity.java) and the application launched on the Samsung device without the exception.

```
public class ButtonClickerNativeActivity extends NativeActivity {
    // Load SO
    static {
        //System.load("libButtonClickerNativeActivity.so");
        System.loadLibrary("ButtonClickerNativeActivity");
    }
```